# Number theory, proprtion, fractions, ratio,

Tags: number-theory

I have three equations:

$\dfrac{a b c}{a+b}=\dfrac{-1}{2}\\\dfrac{a b c}{b+c}=\dfrac{1}{2}\\\dfrac{a b c}{a+c}=1$

then they asked to find $abc$ value which finally will be $a b c =\dfrac{2\sqrt{2}}{15}$.
I think the solution will be obtained by using ration and proportion properties instead of calculating $a, b$ and $c$ separately.

Can you help me to find the solution please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Mathematica:

There are two solutions: a b c = +/- 2 Sqrt[2/15]

```
Clear[a, b, c]

eqns = {
   a b c/(a + b) == -1/2, 
   a b c/(b + c) == 1/2,
   a b c/(a + c) == 1};
```

There are two solutions

```
solns = Solve[eqns, {a, b, c}]
```

[image]

Verification that `solns` satisfies equations

```
And @@ (And @@ eqns /. solns)

(*  True  *)
```

The product `a b c` is then either

```
a b c /. solns
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

$2abc=-a-b=b+c=2a+2c$

$2b=-a-c=2(2a+c)=4a+2c$

$5a+3c=0\iff 5a=-3c$

$10b=-5a-5c=-2c\iff 5b=-c$

$25abc=3c^3=25(a+c)=-15c+25c=10c$

$c^2=10/3$

$abc=10c/25=2c/5=\pm\frac 25\sqrt\frac{10}{3}=\pm\,2\sqrt\frac{2}{15}$